# What are the outcomes of throwing items in the wishing well?

Tags: candy-box-2

In the bottom left of the world map there is a wishing well. By visiting it, it looks like you can throw items into the well, and presumably, make a wish...

[image]

What are the outcomes of throwing items in the wishing well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

candy - health regen, will increase every time you heal. Better not to use it often.
chocolate bar - weapon enchantments
lollipops - convert two lollipops to one candy

> also you will get "pain au chocolate" later, with it you can boost your stats (HP/DMG/Cooldowns)

Answer (score 2):

Also even there is no item in your inventory that can be enchanted, the chocolate bar you throw will not be in vain. When you get an item/items that can be enchanted and go to wishing well it will automatically show enchanting option for the chocolate bar you threw before.

Answer (score 1):

Candies - health

Lollipops - candies

Chocolate - enchantments

Answer (score -1):

In addition to rlex's answer, one may also throw in pains au chocolat. Throwing in pains au chocolat gives you a choice between More Health, More Power and More Magic.